# When to use a "has_many :through" relation in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to understand what `has_many :through` is and when to use it (and how). However, I am not getting it. I am reading Beginning Rails 3 and I tried Googling, but I am not able to understand.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Say you have two models:  `User` and `Group`.

If you wanted to have users belong to groups, then you could do something like this:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
end
```

What if you wanted to track additional metadata around the association?  For example, when the user joined the group, or perhaps what the user's role is in the group?

This is where you make the association a first class object:

```
class GroupMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group

  # has attributes for date_joined and role
end
```

This introduces a new table, and eliminates the `group_id` column from the user's table.

The problem with this code is that you'd have to update every where else you use the user class and change it:

```
user.groups.first.name

# becomes

user.group_memberships.first.group.name
```

This type of code sucks, and it makes introducing changes like this painful.

**`has_many :through`** gives you the best of both worlds:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_memberships  # Edit :needs to be plural same as the has_many relationship   
end
```

Now you can treat it like a normal `has_many`, but get the benefit of the association model when you need it.

Note that you can also do this with `has_one`.

**Edit:  Making it easy to add a user to a group**

```
def add_group(group, role = "member")
  self.group_associations.build(:group => group, :role => role)
end
```

Comment: This is where I'd add a method on the `user` model to add the group.  Something like the edit I just made.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see, do I also have to write `user.groups << group`? Or is everything handled by this association?

Comment: I have a class that is the same as the group_membership and I am having a problems using factory girl with it would u help me?

Comment: I would use "has_many :group_memberships".  Using the singular will work, but user.group_membership will a collection and user.group_memberships won't work.

Comment: That was a typo.  Fixed.

Comment: Is there a typo in the first code section? Should user `belongs_to :groups` instead of  `has_many :groups` or am I missing something else? Thanks.

Comment: Is this kind of like delegation? We're delegating the `groups` method to the `group_membership` model? Is that a good way to think of it?

Comment: What if you want groups to stand alone? Then a user can join and leave a group at any point. Would you use has_many or has_many through??

Comment: Excellent explanation!

Comment: I think there is a typo in the `add_group` method. Shouldn't be `self.group_memberships.build(:group => group, :role => role)` instead of `self.group_associations.build(:group => group, :role => role)`?

Answer (score 278):

Say you have these models:

```
Car
Engine
Piston
```

A car `has_one :engine`
An engine `belongs_to :car`
An engine `has_many :pistons`
Piston `belongs_to :engine`

A car `has_many :pistons, through: :engine`
Piston `has_one :car, through: :engine`

Essentially you are delegating a model relationship to another model, so instead of having to call `car.engine.pistons`, you can just do `car.pistons`

Comment: I call this SACA - ShortAndClearAnswer.

Comment: In this example we have 3 models. What if we want more than 3 models? e.g. a doctor/patient app where they can message. Then User has_one Patient has_many Appointments has_one Conversation has_many Messages. Then the conversation for an appointment could be retrieved with `current_user.patient.appointment.last.conversation.messages`. Is there a such thing as *nested* has_many through ?

Comment: Really what we're talking about here is active record relationships. It's about the SQL query and how related data can be fetched.

Answer (score 23):

#### ActiveRecord Join Tables

`has_many :through` and `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships function through a *join table*, which is an intermediate table that represents the relationship between other tables. Unlike a JOIN query, data is actually stored in a table.

#### Practical Differences

With `has_and_belongs_to_many`, you don't need a primary key, and you access the records through ActiveRecord relations rather than through an ActiveRecord model. You usually use HABTM when you want to link two models with a many-to-many relationship.

You use a `has_many :through` relationship when you want to interact with the join table as a Rails model, complete with primary keys and the ability to add custom columns to the joined data. The latter is particularly important for data that is relevant to the joined rows, but doesn't really belong to the related models--for example, storing a calculated value derived from the fields in the joined row.

#### See Also

In [A Guide to Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many), the recommendation reads:

> The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a has_many :through relationship if you need to work with the relationship model as an independent entity. If you don’t need to do anything with the relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship (though you’ll need to remember to create the joining table in the database).
>
> You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks, or extra attributes on the join model.