# Difficulty with belongs_to and has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm rather confused by the construction and have tried several ways to get the following situation to work for my test. But I can't get it to work.

This is what I want:
When an activity is being made. Several clients can be assigned to that activity. Therefore creating access to `@oneActivity.clients` or `@oneClient.activities`.

Should I put up a `references :client` in my activity migration or the other way around? And which of the two should have to `belongs_to` in the model and which the `has_many`?

Comment: The information may not be complete. You've indicated that an activity can have many clients. Can a client have many activities?

Comment: I said no. But yes. A client has many activities.

Comment: I think Client has many activities and as you said a single activity belongs to many client...so use many to many relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well if a client has many activities and an activity has many clients then i suggest you take a look at has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.in that case

in your Client model you would have

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :activities
```

and in your Activity Model you would have

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
```

that way you can do the actions you described in your question

You can check out relationships from the rails guides here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: I actually had it like this. And someone told me to do it otherwise. Because when I try to test stuff it says `undefined method `client=' for #<Activity:0x75ab078>`.

Comment: well it would be better if you post your tests but this can happen if you call activity.client. You have to call it like so: activity.clients. it should be plural because it is a many to many relationship

Comment: Ah, fixed that aswell. I use `clients {[FactoryGirl.create(:client)]}` now instead of `association :client` in my activity factory.

Can you use this both ways? Because if i add the same for activity in my client factory it becomes an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, from what you describe, that you need a many-to-many relationship. Clients can have many activities, and activities can, as you describe, be assigned to several clients.

Setting up such a relationship is described in the following question [When should one use a "has_many :through" relation in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600928/when-should-one-use-a-has-many-through-relation-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

in your Client model you would have

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :activities
```

and in your Activity Model you would have

```
has_and_belongs_to_may :clients
```