# Rails: Assigning another user to an excisting entry (associations)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have 2 models in my project. 1 is Users and 1 is courses. 
A user has many courses 
and courses has many users. 
The main problem is that I can't figure out how to assign users to courses without creating a new course.

```
user = User.first 
course = Course.new(title:"course01")
```

My output would then be something like

```
Course id: 2, title: "course01", created_at: "2016-03-20 07:05:23",            
updated_at: "2016-03-20 07:05:23", user_id: 1>
```

Now I can't figure out how to add another user to this same course.

```
user = User.second
?
```

Comment: Read up on has_many :through type of association here [has_many :through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) Hope this link guides you in the right direction.

Comment: The assigning of the user_id to the course works. I just can't figure out how to add another user so the same course.

Comment: You will need a model in between that connects a user and a course, which can be implemented with has_many :though association.

Comment: You were completly right. This helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600928/when-should-one-use-a-has-many-through-relation-in-rails

Comment: you have to HABTM relationship between course & user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `user_id` from `courses` table, no need of it

Create join table for HABTM

```
create_table :users_courses, id: false do |t|
  t.references :course
  t.references :user
end
```

In `user.rb` file

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
```

In `course.rb` file

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

after creating new course

```
course = Course.create(title:"course01")
users = User.all or whatever you need to assign to same course
users.each do |user|
  course.users << user ##assign 
end
```

In rails console

```
course = Course.first or Course.find(1) or whatever you want 
course.users << User.find(1) or whatever you want
```

Comment: thanks! what is the code if I want to assign a user manually to the course in rails console?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say a new 'UserCourseAssignment' is created when a user is assigned to a course.

You could create a new UserCourseAssignment model with attributes user_id & course_id to store which users are assigned to which courses. This new table will have a new entry every time a user is assigned to a course.

User model

```
has_many :user_course_assignments

has_many :courses, through: :user_course_assignments
```

Course model

```
has_many :user_course_assignments

has_many :users, though: :user_course_assignments
```

UserCourseAssignment model

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :course
```

Edit:
I think you currently have user_id attribute in Course model. You won't need it after implementing the has_many :through association.

Comment: Thanks, one more question I have created a course and assigned a user to it. In my code I want to assign only if the user is not yet enrolled. I have this but I want it only to happen if the current_user is not yet assigned to this course:
     def beginnerscourse_01
       user = current_user 
       course = Course.find(5)
       user.courses << course
       user.save
       course.save
      end
    end

Already so much thanks guys @LHH

Comment: In that case, make the assignment unless the course is already among current_user's enrollments. Like so - 

`def beginnerscourse_01
    course = Course.find(5)
    unless current_user.user_course_assignments.find_by(course_id: course.id)
        # Enroll
    end
end`