# Two levels of HABTM associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the classes Student, Classroom and Course. A Student has and belongs to many classrooms, and a Classroom has and belongs to many courses.

How do I retrieve all the courses associated with a Student? Also, how do I retrieve all students associated with a course?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`has_many ... :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) in your model (`models/student.rb`):

```
has_many :courses, :through => :classrooms   
has_many :classrooms
```

Then you can use :

```
student.courses
```

Some useful stackoverflow link : [When should one use a "has_many :through" relation in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600928/when-should-one-use-a-has-many-through-relation-in-rails)