# how to get data from 2 rails join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

i have a join table between alarms and lists, and have a join table between lists and cars, i want to find the alarm to be notified when a certain car is added in a certain list, i tried to use `alarm.list.cars` but that's doesn't work
any help please
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you're looking for a `has_many_through` relationship. You might want to look at these. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/what-is-a-has_many-through-association-in-ruby-on-rails-treehouse-quick-tip  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600928/when-should-one-use-a-has-many-through-relation-in-rails

Comment: in alarm model i made 
has_and_belongs_to_many :cars, through: :list 
and in car model i made that 
has_one :alarms, through: :list
but when i try to call alarm.list.car
it gives an error