# rails has_many through with 5 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to know if is a good practice create a has_many through with more than 2 tables. for exemple:

I have

```
class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :hex
  has_many :colorships
  has_many :products, :through => :orderships
  has_many :orders, :through => :orderships
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :orders

end

class Size < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  attr_accessible :size
 # has_many :orders 
  has_many :orderships
  has_many :products, :through => :orderships
  has_many :orders, :through => :orderships
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :orders

end



class Condition < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :condition
  has_many :products



 has_many :orderships
  has_many :products, :through => :orderships
  has_many :orders, :through => :orderships

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :orders


end


class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :orderships
  has_many :products, :through => :orderships
  has_many :orders, :through => :orderships

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :orders



end
```

The most part the exemples just show 2 models relation

```
class Material < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name



 has_many :orderships
  has_many :products, :through => :orderships
  has_many :orders, :through => :orderships

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :orders


end


class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :orderships
  has_many :colors, :through => :orderships
  has_many :sizes, :through => :orderships
  has_many :materials, :through => :orderships
  has_many :brands, :through => :orderships
  has_many :conditions, :through => :orderships
end
```

So, seems that overblunder the models.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :orderships
  has_many :colors, :through => :orderships
  has_many :sizes, :through => :orderships
  has_many :materials, :through => :orderships
  has_many :brands, :through => :orderships
  has_many :conditions, :through => :orderships

end
```

with relations but at leat dry out models

```
class Ordership < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  attr_accessible :product_id, :size_id, :order_id,:condition_id,:brand_id,:material_id
  #
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :color
   belongs_to :order
 belongs_to:condition
 belongs_to:material
 belongs_to:Brand
end
```

Comment: If your code works and you just want recommendations of how to write it better you should consider putting it on [codereview.se] rather than [so]. I'd also recommend using a spelling checker.

Comment: i dont tested. i just would like to know if is possible without problems

Comment: Every time I see a `has_many :through` I wonder if this is just a way to hide a violation of the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: Maybe this helps, when deciding to go with `has_many :through` associations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11601236/5243191