# ActiveRecord association through multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have the following schema for my Rails app :

[image]
A project has many reviews, each of those reviews is filled out by a unique User to calculate a global score.

We could say that "An Organization of Users handles many Entities that have many Projects which are reviewed by the Users".

As you can see, I have a circular reference since I linked the tables "Users" & "Reviews".

After many tries and many search, I just can't manage to associate a User to a Review...Here is what I did so far:

**1. Creation of an association table "UserReviews"**

**2. Model User**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organization

  ####

  has_many :user_reviews
  has_many :reviews, through: :user_reviews
end
```

**3. Model Review**

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project

  ##

  belongs_to :user_reviews
  has_one :user, through: :user_reviews
end
```

**4. Model UserReview**

```
class UserReview < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :review
end
```

I want to be able to get user.reviews or review.user.

Basically...I have to admit I'm lost despite the documentation. I never had to deal with this kind of issue.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Could this be what your are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600928/when-should-one-use-a-has-many-through-relation-in-rails

Comment: I saw that but unfortunately I can't apply it properly to my model...!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need UserReview model here? I suppose Review model suffices your use case.

Change the **Review** model to:

```rb
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Isn't a join table needed here? I thought a "through" link was mandatory in that case?

Comment: @Aurel A review is uniq based on `user_id` and `project_id`. you should add a `uniqueness` validation on `user_id, project_id`